# How to access id of an element in listview before listview listener is called?

Tags: java, android, listview

I want to access id of element which is in listview before onItemClickListener is called.

Here Is My Code.

This code create onClickListener for Image.

```
        deleteImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            currentSchedulerUridelete = 
        ContentUris.withAppendedId(schedulerEntry.CONTENT_URI,);
            deleteDialog(v);
        }
    });
```

This is the deleteDialog method which is called when the Image is Clicked

```
        public void deleteDialog(View view){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext());
        builder.setMessage("Delete this Work?");
        builder.setPositiveButton("DELETE", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                // User clicked the "Delete" button, so delete the pet.
                //currentSchedulerUri = 
       ContentUris.withAppendedId(schedulerEntry.CONTENT_URI,id);
                deletePet(view);
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                // User clicked the "Cancel" button, so dismiss the dialog
                // and continue editing the pet.
                if (dialog != null) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });

        // Create and show the AlertDialog
        AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
    }
```

This is the Delete Pet Method

```
     private void deletePet(View view){
     if(currentSchedulerUridelete != null){
            int rowsDeleted = 
     view.getContext().getContentResolver().delete(currentSchedulerUridelete,null,null);
         if (rowsDeleted == 0) {
             // If no rows were deleted, then there was an error with the delete.
             Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "WORK DOES NOT DELETE",
                     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         } else {
             // Otherwise, the delete was successful and we can display a toast.
             Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "WORK DELETED",
                     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }
     }
    }
```

This is the OnItemClickListener method in which the uri is there which i need but it is accessed after onItemClickListener is called but i need it before.

```
        getListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MyWork.this,newWork.class);
            currentSchedulerUri  = ContentUris.withAppendedId(schedulerEntry.CONTENT_URI,id);
            intent.setData(currentSchedulerUri);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

and this listener is in another activity.

Pls Help Me Solve This Problem.
Thanks In Advance.
Thank You.

Comment: That id is rowId you should not be using it . Use position instead what are you trying to do with id anyway ?. Also u should not be using a `ListView` its been replaced by `RecyclerView` half decade ago . better not use legacy widgets ..

Comment: yes thanks for telling i will do it. but these does not solve my problem.pls tell if you have solution to the problem.

Comment: If you want to make changes in second activity based on click in first activity, you have to either pass it through setResult https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#setResult(int,%20android.content.Intent) or with for example repository pattern https://developer.android.com/topic/architecture#data-layer